# How can I split a String and keep the delimiters in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, split

I am new to Swift, I come from Java background. I want to make a struct for parsing input for a calculator. Here is my code

```
struct Parse {
    var runningCalc: String
    
    init(runningCalc: String) {
        self.runningCalc = runningCalc
    }
    
    mutating func toArray(String: runningCalc){
        runningCalc = runningCalc.split()
    }
}
```

I want to have input of a string, and have it return a string Array with delimiters of
`{ +-/*()%}.`

In java you could do a string tokenizer to keep the delimiters in the returned string array.

How can I use the split or components method to separate my string input to a string array?

Comment: You could use [this variant of split](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893447-split) or [components(separatedBy:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410120-components) perhaps, depending on what it is exactly that you want to do

Comment: @JoakimDanielson OP is trying to keep the delimiters

Answer (score 2):

I personally wouldn't use a struct. It's more common to extend an existing type with additional functionality. So, you want the components of a `String` that includes delimiters? Sounds like you want to extend `String`. Since `String` conforms to `StringProtocol` I'd extend `StringProtocol` so that any other types that conform to `StringProtocol` get this new functionality for free:

`StringProtocol` already has a method called `components(separatedBy:)` which takes a `CharacterSet` (a set of characters) to delimit the receiver.

Let's implement a method similar to the existing `StringProtocol` method.

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func components(separatedByIncluding delims: CharacterSet) -> [String] {
        var components: [String] = []
        var component = ""

        for character in self {
            if String(character).rangeOfCharacter(from: delims) != nil {
                if !component.isEmpty {
                    components.append(component)
                }
                components.append(String(character))
                component = ""
            } else {
                component += [character]
            }
        }
        if !component.isEmpty {
            components.append(component)
        }

        return components
    }
}
```

The method loops over each `Character` and checks if it's a delimiter. If so, it adds a new `String` to the array consisting of the delimiter `Character`. If not, it constructs a substring consisting of non-delimiter `Character` values. The resulting array of delimiters and substrings are then returned.

Usage would be:

```
func testExample() throws {
    let delims = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "{ +-/*()%}")
    let text = "{abc def+ghi-jkl/mno"

    let components = text.components(separatedByIncluding: delims)

    print("================")
    print(components)
    print("================")
}
```

The result is:

```
================
["{", "abc", " ", "def", "+", "ghi", "-", "jkl", "/", "mno"]
================
```

Comment: This looks much simpler than mine. I tried to add the same functionality from the original split method, make it generic as well, and to do not duplicate the already existent string by returning subsequences instead of strings.

Comment: Yeah, after some trying I realized that a basic loop was the simplest solution.

Comment: Ah, good catch Leo

Comment: Answer has been updated with a fix

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I copy and paste your extension and function code to a Swift class file, I get an Error: Invalid redeclaration of 'components(separatedByIncluding:)' Edit: I do not get the same error when pasting it to a Swift Playground

Comment: @KyleZeller You have probably pasted it twice in your project

Comment: I don't think I did paste it twice, though I checked if a few minutes ago and the error was gone. Couldn't tell you why. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no native Swift split method that allows you to keep the delimiters. You will need to implement your own split method extending `Collection`. Special thanks for [@MartinR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/274300/126010) and [@Rob](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/274438/126010) for the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/274296/126010):

```
extension Collection {
    func splitAndKeep(
        maxSplits: Int = .max,
        omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool = true,
        whereSeparator isSeparator: (Element) throws -> Bool
    ) rethrows -> [SubSequence] {
        precondition(maxSplits >= 0, "maxSplits can not be negative")
        if isEmpty { return [] }
        var subsequences: [SubSequence] = []
        var lowerBound = startIndex
        func appendAndAdvance(with upperBound: Index) {
            let range = lowerBound..<upperBound
            if !omittingEmptySubsequences || !range.isEmpty {
                subsequences.append(self[range])
                lowerBound = upperBound
            }
        }
        while
            var upperBound = try self[lowerBound...].firstIndex(where: isSeparator),
            subsequences.count < maxSplits {
            appendAndAdvance(with: upperBound)
            if subsequences.count == maxSplits {
                break
            }
            formIndex(after: &upperBound)
            appendAndAdvance(with: upperBound)
        }
        appendAndAdvance(with: endIndex)
        return subsequences
    }
}
```

---

```
let string = "*(22+13)/"
let delimiters = Set<Character>("{+-/*()%}.")

let ss = string.splitAndKeep(whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["*", "(", "22", "+", "13", ")", "/"]
let ss1 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 0, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["*(22+13)/"]
let ss2 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 1, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["*", "(22+13)/"]
let ss3 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 2, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["*", "(", "22+13)/"]

let ss4 = string.splitAndKeep(omittingEmptySubsequences: false, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["", "*", "", "(", "22", "+", "13", ")", "", "/", ""]["", "*", "", "(", "22", "+", "13", ")", "", "/", ""]
let ss5 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 0, omittingEmptySubsequences: false, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["*(22+13)/"]
let ss6 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 1, omittingEmptySubsequences: false, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["", "*(22+13)/"]
let ss7 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 2, omittingEmptySubsequences: false, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["", "*", "(22+13)/"]
```